# Apache Ignite SqlFieldsQuery cursor issue

Tags: java, sql, caching, ignite

I'm using SqlFieldsQuery for cache with ~1_000_000 rows.

```
QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select num from some_cache"))
```

I've read about the query cursors lazy nature (http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/cache-queries#section-querycursor). But it seems that all the data from cache is loaded at once. Because my query takes long time and cursor.getAll() returns collection with all the data immediately.

Is this lack of some configuration or it's expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`getAll` indeed returns all rows at once.

`QueryCursor` extends `Iterable`, use iterator to leverage laziness.

```
QueryCursor<List> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select num from some_cache"))
for (List l : cursor)
    doSomething(l);
```

Comment: I've used `getAll` just to test that data is already loaded. I want to say that it seems that all the data had been already loaded during `cache.query` (without calling `getAll`)

Comment: Well, looks like the query takes more time than results retrieval. This does not mean that lazy loading does not work.